# Python reports "ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded"

Tags: python, json

I got this error message when trying to extract the object into specific elements

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "twitter_mining.py", line 17, in <module>
    tweets_data = json.loads(tweets_data_path)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 339, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 364, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 382, in raw_decode
    raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
```

My code

```
tweets_data_path = 'data.txt'
tweets_data = json.loads(tweets_data_path)
tweets = pd.DataFrame()
tweets['text'] = map(lambda tweet: tweet['text'], tweets_data)
```

Data - http://intellij.my/rnd/nlp/sentiment-analysis/data.txt

Comment: `json.loads` expects *a JSON string*, not a string containing the path to a file maybe containing JSON.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`json.loads` does not accept a file name as an argument.

Read the content of the file and pass that to `loads` instead.

```
tweets_data_path = 'data.txt'
with open(tweets_data_path) as file:
    tweets_data = json.loads(file.read())
```

Or use `load`.

```
tweets_data_path = 'data.txt'
with open(tweets_data_path) as file:
    tweets_data = json.load(file)
```

Answer (score 2):

This should do it:

```
with open('data.txt') as tweets_data_path:
    tweets_data = json.load(tweets_data_path)
```